# Set key type when using "key in ObjectName"

Tags: typescript

I am trying to set the key type of an object like this:

```
type TypeSample = {
    [key: string]: string
}
```

While also specifying that the keys come from an enum like this:

```
enum EnumSample {
    'ok' = '200',
}

type TypeSample = {
    [key in EnumSample]: string
}
```

Not setting the key type causes the error `Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'TypeSample'` to appear on my "getter" function.

**My Question:** How can I modify "TypeSample" to let TypeScript know it will only ever have keys that are strings?

NOTE: It is important to other parts of the code that "EnumSample" is actually a ENUM and not a TYPE/INTERFACE.

---

### Context:

Here is a condensed version of the code I am working with:

```
enum SupportedHttpStatuses {
    'ok' = '200',
    'badRequest' = '400',
    'imATeapotSafe' = '418a',
    'imATeapot' = '418b',
}

type StatusMapType = {
    [key in SupportedHttpStatuses]: StatusType // I want to set the key type here
}

type StatusType = {
    code: number, // status code to send to the browser
    title: string, // error title
    description: string // error description
}

class Test {
    public static STATUS_MAP: StatusMapType = {
        '200': {
            code: 200,
            title: 'OK',
            description: 'This request has succeeded.',
        },
        '400': {
            code: 400,
            title: 'Bad Request',
            description: 'This request is missing data or contains invalid information.',
        },
        '418a': {
            code: 200,
            title: 'I\'m A Teapot!',
            description: 'This request was successful but it is april fools day.',
        },
        '418b': {
            code: 418,
            title: 'I\'m A Teapot!',
            description: 'This request was successful but it is april fools day.',
        },
    }

    public static async getStatusMap(statusId: string): Promise<StatusType> {
        return this.STATUS_MAP[statusId] // Element implicitly has an 'any' type because expression of type 'string' can't be used to index type 'StatusMapType'
    }
}
```

Comment: I don't have a solution, but every time i work with enums in typescript it's a pain. I don't know where I read this, but I remember reading that `enum` was a very early feature and would probably not have made it to typescript today as they break a few design rules. I try to avoid them.

Comment: Maybe I'm missing something, but I think you just need to change statusId: string to statusId: SupportedHttpStatuses in getStatusMap.

Comment: @Countingstuff Welp that indirectly solved my problem. Add that as an answer and you will get at least an upvote. Technically it doesn't answer the actual question, so I want to give someone else a chance to answer that before I mark yours as the actual answer.

Comment: The comment looks like the right answer to me.  The compiler knows that all the valid keys will be strings, but it *doesn't* think that all strings are valid keys, because you told it that the keys will only be the strings in that enum.  Indexing into that object with a `string` is not known to be safe, because it could be some random string that doesn't exist in the object.  What would you consider an actual answer?

Comment: @Countingstuff The more I think about it, the more yours is correct. If you add yours as an answer then I will mark it as the correct answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would suggest you change the signature of

`getStatusMap(statusId: string): Promise<StatusType>`

to

`getStatusMap(statusId: SupportedHttpStatuses): Promise<StatusType>`

this.STATUS_MAP[statusId] will then know that statusId is a SupportedHttpStatuses and hence when STATUS_MAP is indexed will return a StatusType